# Analytics / Tag Manager Difference between Event & Page view values

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to understand why a Page View and Event would give two different numbers for the exact same task in GA with GTM.

In my google analytics when I check my `Page Views` for a specific page inside "Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages". Analytics tells me I have had **3600** Unique views.

But I also have an `Event` that on each page it delivers the page type & title. But when I check the event values in "Behaviour > Events" I get the value of **4100** unique views.

Surely these values should be identical because they both are unique views based on session and fire from the same trigger. If anything I would expect the event to have been lower.

I have added to the data layer of every page like:

```
dataLayer = [{
'pageType': '<?php echo $pageType; ?>',
'pageName': '<?php $pageTitle; ?>',
}];
</script>
    <?php echo $TagManager; ?>
```

And with this the tag in GTM is something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique pageview metric increments only once per session per page.

The unique events metric increments on unique combinations of Event Category, Event Action and Event Label.

Even though both of your GA tags in GTM use the same trigger, I suspect that there could possibly be at least differences in the variables for the Event Label field.

One way you can tell is by looking at the "Pages" report under Behavior > Events, then look at the events happening on pages, see if the labels are different.

Comment: Well yes the labels will be different due to page paths being different. so this would be the cause then because labels arent 100% identical

Comment: So what you are saying is if someone triggers the event but then changes path causing a different label for the same even that same person has caused multiple unique events

Comment: Since the page type, page name and page path variables are used, if any of those can vary, it will create a new unique event. Events are case sensitive.

Comment: gotcha (Y), Accepted answer